# Tomcat: Custom error page not working

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, web.xml

Well this should've been simple enough. I modified the project's web.xml in order to display my own error page for 500's:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Then I wrote the simplest servlet in order to test it:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
}
```

The custom page (which is located at the root directory) is then completely ignored and I get the default Tomcat error page instead.

I'm using the Tomcat 6 version that comes with the debugger of MyEclipse. I've tripled-checked this for typos, but I can't find anything unusual. I'm wondering whether the *error-page* tag needs to be in a certain part of the document. Does anyone know what could be going wrong?

*Edit:
This is the full web.xml that was requested:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" 

    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

<display-name></display-name>

<jsp-config> 
   <jsp-property-group> 
      <url-pattern>/js/base.js</url-pattern>
      <url-pattern>/js/catalog.base.js</url-pattern>
      <url-pattern>/js/minicatalog.base.js</url-pattern>
      <url-pattern>/js/addresses.js</url-pattern>
   </jsp-property-group> 
</jsp-config>

<mime-mapping>
    <extension>pdf</extension>
    <mime-type>application/pdf</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/index.jsp?redirect=1</location>
</error-page-->

<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>

<!-- BASE -->
<servlet>
    <description>User entity methods.</description>
    <display-name>User</display-name>
    <servlet-name>UserServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sitei.base.servlet.UserServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>UserServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet/UserServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <description>Person entity methods.</description>
    <display-name>Person</display-name>
    <servlet-name>PersonServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sitei.base.servlet.PersonServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>PersonServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet/PersonServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <description>Company entity methods.</description>
    <display-name>Company</display-name>
    <servlet-name>CompanyServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sitei.base.servlet.CompanyServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CompanyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet/CompanyServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <description>Module entity methods.</description>
    <display-name>Module</display-name>
    <servlet-name>ModuleServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sitei.base.servlet.ModuleServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ModuleServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet/ModuleServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <description>Profile entity methods.</description>
    <display-name>Profile</display-name>
    <servlet-name>ProfileServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sitei.base.servlet.ProfileServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ProfileServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet/ProfileServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <description>Address entity methods.</description>
    <display-name>Address</display-name>
    <servlet-name>AddressServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sitei.base.servlet.AddressServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AddressServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet/AddressServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<!-- END BASE -->

<!-- PUSH -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>icepush</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.icepush.servlet.ICEpushServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>icepush</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.icepush</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<!-- END PUSH -->

<!-- TRUCKS -->
<servlet>
    <description>Employee entity methods.</description>
    <display-name>Employee</display-name>
    <servlet-name>EmployeeServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sitei.trucks.servlet.EmployeeServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>EmployeeServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet/EmployeeServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <description>Vehicle entity methods.</description>
    <display-name>Vehicle</display-name>
    <servlet-name>VehicleServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sitei.trucks.servlet.VehicleServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>VehicleServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet/VehicleServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <description>VehicleBrand entity methods.</description>
    <display-name>VehicleBrand</display-name>
    <servlet-name>VehicleBrandServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sitei.trucks.servlet.VehicleBrandServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>VehicleBrandServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet/VehicleBrandServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <description>Report methods.</description>
    <display-name>Report</display-name>
    <servlet-name>ReportServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sitei.trucks.servlet.ReportServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ReportServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet/ReportServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <description>ExpenseLog methods.</description>
    <display-name>ExpenseLog</display-name>
    <servlet-name>ExpenseLogServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sitei.trucks.servlet.ExpenseLogServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ExpenseLogServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet/ExpenseLogServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <description>IncomeLog methods.</description>
    <display-name>IncomeLog</display-name>
    <servlet-name>IncomeLogServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sitei.trucks.servlet.IncomeLogServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>IncomeLogServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet/IncomeLogServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <description>FileExport methods.</description>
    <display-name>FileExport</display-name>
    <servlet-name>FileExportServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sitei.trucks.servlet.FileExportServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FileExportServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet/FileExportServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<!-- END TRUCKS -->

<session-config>
  <session-timeout>15</session-timeout> 
</session-config>

<!--security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>LOGIN</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint-->

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: what do you mean by ** I get the default Tomcat error page instead ** => a 404 page?

Comment: Nope, it's not a 404 as in "the error page was not found", it's the regular 500 page that was shown before I changed web.xml

Comment: and your the page `error.jsp` is directly under the `webapp` folder?

Comment: Yes, the *error.jsp* page is in the root folder. The servlet is not, but I suppose that it shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Yes, it works if I access it directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
```

will send out a reponse with http status 500. This is stating an internal error, but does not issue one in your application.

Try

```
throw new ServletException();
```

instead and you'll see your configuration is working as expected.

Comment: Thanks! That was it, I knew that it would have to be something very simple. It seems that the page is opened from the current URL because it is shown without the CSS and images, but I guess I'll just use absolute paths then.

Answer (score 17):

In the servlet, you should call:

```
response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
```

Instead of:

```
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
```

The setStatus is used to set the return status code when there is no error (for example,
for the status codes `SC_OK` or `SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY`). If there is an error, the `sendError` method should be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

What does your web.xml look like?  Particularly the servlet/filter mapping?  You may need to add `<dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>` to your servlet/filter mapping.

Comment: Thanks, let me try that then. I added the full web.xml above.

Comment: I added a filter to see if I could redirect to my error page manually, but *<dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>* is ignored as well. If I use *<dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>* I can get the filter to run, otherwise the break point will never be hit. It's one of those errors that make less sense the more you investigate.